# Net connection is not showing in PCB view in Altium

Tags: altium

I don't find why in PCB view, my component(highlighted) is not connected to chip whereas in schematic it is connected to the chip and there no error in the schematic.The highlighted cap(C307,100nF) is not showing any white line to the chip VDDC. [image]

The VDDC is a pin which is visible on the IC.
[image]

Please find this **unknown pin: pin Cxxx-x error** while updating the schematic to PCB which I saw now.[image]

**Also, i find a small circle on each component. how can I remove them?**
[image]

I am new to Altium. Hope to hear from you guys soon.

Comment: You have to fix all the errors first. If there are errors, the design will never update correctly.

Comment: The circles are error markers. You remove them by figuring out what the error is and fixing it. I can't say this enough times. Fix the errors before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, Altium shows the air-wires only between the component and the ***nearest*** pad/track/via of the same net. It does not show airwires to ***all*** connections with the same net. That would leave to a **VERY** messy ratsnest that would not help with routing at all. If you drag the highlighted capacitor closer to the IC than to the other capacitor, you will see the airwire jump to the IC pad instead.

Comment: But there should still be an air-wire from either C307 or C308 to some other place they're connected. And the net should be named `VDDC` instead of `NetC307_1`. OP are you sure you've updated the PCB with all your schematic changes? What net label shows on pin 38 of the chip?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the schematic and PCB. But the net is not showing.

Comment: @ThePhoton I don't agree with you regarding there still being an airwire from one of the caps to some other place. The nearest pad of the same net for each capacitor is the other capacitor. I'd like the OP to do as I suggested and move one of the capacitors closer to the connected IC pad than to the other capacitor pad and see if the airwire jumps. I am 95% sure it will. Also, not sure what happened with the net names there. Probably off-grid. To the OP, do not put your net labels at the end of the wires like that. Put it *along* the wires.

Comment: Yes, if I move the cap closer to the IC also, I do not see any air ware.

Comment: @litunbls After fixing the nets? What is the net name of the IC pad you're trying to connect to?

Comment: As you can see in the picture VDDC is the IC pad name where I am trying to connect the cap. But in Altium PCB view I do not see the air ware from the cap to VDDC.

Comment: @litunbls Did you fix the nets of the capacitors you want to connect to VDDC? You haven't shown that, you've only shown the ones connecting to VDDP. Make sure all of the pads that are supposed to be connected have the same net name. Also, make sure all of your connections are shown. Go to View -> Connections -> Show All (shortcut VCS)

Comment: The "unknown pin" error is definitely important. It means it was not able to match the footprint to the schematic component. Make sure you have the right footprint connected to your schematic component, and that each pad in the footprint has the same designator as its matching pin in the schematic (i.e. pin 1, pin 2). If the designators are named differently, they will not be matched in the PCB.

Comment: Yah... I have downloaded the IC library(for Altium) from Infineon website.[link](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/motor-control-ics/automotive-embedded-power-ics-system-on-chip-/3-phase-bridge-driver-with-integrated-arm-cortex-m3/tle9879qxa40/#!boards) Do I need to open the library and see what they have done?  Or you are talking about using the library in my schematic has some problem?

Comment: There are way too many variables at play right now to say for sure. This is why I make my own libraries and library components. It takes away a lot of uncertainty. Honestly, I think that would be your best bet. Make your own library for your parts. I have a tutorial on Youtube (look up "DerStrom8 Altium Library Tutorial") on how to do that. It gives you a lot more control and makes sure you can easily fix problems like this. You *could* edit the Infineon libraries manually, but I think that would be more of a pain in the neck

Comment: @Destrom8, All the air-wires for a particular net should form a connected graph. There shouldn't be any isolated subsets that aren't connected between each other.

Comment: There is certainly no rule that there should only be one air-wire connected to each pad.

Comment: @ThePhoton Perhaps you're right, I'm going from memory here.

Answer (score 0):

What is ringing my alarm bells, is that the schematic grid doesn't match the one of the tracks. You seems to be working with a metric cursor grid, while using a imperial page grid.

For sake of your sanity, you should always work in the grid in which the library was designed, otherwise you risk to come across problems like the one you are experiencing.

It is hard to tell from the pictures but you can see in the PCB that the two capacitors that are connected together have a new net name (NETC307_1).

In the schematic, try to hover over the net connected to the capacitors, you are likely to see exactly that name. 
The easiest way out of it, is to remove the existing wire, and place it again, making sure that when you click when placing the wire, the cursor shows a red X; only then you can be sure that the connection is what you want.